# Pass Html code from Controller to JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, uiviewcontroller, validation

I want to pass html data from Controller to JSP.

I am using `Spring MVC` and `'Spring Validator'` populates messages on the JSP:

```
@Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
//Some processing     
errors.rejectValue("fileData", "errors.csi.invalidurl", new Object[] { url }, null);
}
```

message.properties

```
errors.csi.invalidurl=File contained invalid URLs. Please find list of invalid URLs <a href="{0}"> here</a>.
```

Corresponding JSP is:

```
<div class="row">
<label for="upload-file"><spring:message code="csi.label.uploadfile"/></label><form:input path="fileData" type="file"/>
<form:errors path="fileData" cssClass="error"/>
</div>
```

I am able to pass text data but unable to pass href links. How could it be done?

I tried

```
String url = "javascript:getImageValidationPresignedURLForDownload('8162')"; to be passed as text data but it is displayed as text.

URLs <a href="javascript:getImageValidationPresignedURLForDownload('8162')"> here</a>.
```

What am I doing wrong? How could it be done?

Thanks,

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*: 1. Generating HTML in your controller, 2. not showing your code.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added JSP code if that's what you meant. How could it be done? How can I pass a clickable link (html code) or generate it as per validation behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<form:errors path="fileData" cssClass="error" htmlEscape="false" />
```